# Using Dynamic Docker Ports in Postman

Tags: docker, postman

I am experimenting with Dynamic Port Ranges, nothing is concrete here.

The dynamic ports have their flaws but I have not had any conflicts yet with any other containers/images. All the containers are working with different URLs with their port extensions: `localhost:8001` or `localhost:8002`. Now if we `docker down` and `docker up` the ports increase.

Example: If I `docker down` the container using port 8001, when I do `docker up`, it maps it to 8003 and so on until 8010 and then it starts back at 8001.

docker-compose.yaml file

```
services:
  symfony:
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-symfony
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www:delegated
    ports:
      - "8001-8010:80"
    env_file:
      - .env
```

**Problem**

If we want to setup routes in Postman and I setup a new environment for a URL environment variable - while setting up the URL I have to type `localhost:8001` but then if we `docker down` and then `docker up` and it the new host port becomes `localhost:8003` the URL Environment Variable isn't going to work.

Is there a way for Postman to read the docker container name and get the image URL or some type of integration with Docker so the dynamic port or the full URL is automatically pulled into a Postman Environment Variable so we can use it?